# I was wondering how to correctly write a try except statement?

Tags: python-3.x

For this code I am trying to import some numbers then export them out of the program (which is working fine). The problem I am running into is that the code exits out of the do while statement before the code is finished reading the .txt document, I think because of the try expect statement. I need help in trying to fix this statement.

```
print("This program shows acceleration over time and puts them in a text file.")
speed = 0
t = 0
acc = 0
file = open("Output_FileP3v2.txt", "w")
file2 = open("P3v2_Input.txt","r")
dt = float(file2.readline())
while (dt != ""):
    file.write('t,acc,speed\n')
    file.write(str(t) + "," + str(acc) + "," + str(speed) + "\n")
    while(speed < 100):
        acc = acc + 5
        speed = speed + acc * dt
        t = t + dt
        file.write(str(t) + "," + str(acc) + "," + str(speed) + "\n")     
    acc = 0
    while (t <= 5):                     
        t = t + 1
        file.write(str(t) + "," + str(acc) + str(speed) + "\n")       
    while (speed > 0):                  
        acc = acc - 5
        speed = speed + acc * dt
        t = t + dt
        file.write(str(t) + "," + str(acc) + "," + str(speed) + "\n")  
    try :
        dt = float(dt = read.readline())
        print
    except:
        dt = ""               #here is where I think I am having the trouble. the program is setting it to "" before the code is finished reading the .txt document and I dont know why.
    print ("hi")              #to show how many times the while statement ran.
print ("The program just sent a list of code in a text document to where the program file is saved.")
file.close()
file2.close()
```

Comment: Perhaps `float` fails when it encounters a string that it can't parse as a float?

Comment: Why not print the Exception,error and post the error info ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, the print statement being a function requires parenthesis instead of just `print`. Change to `print()`, and your method should work.

For more information, check out the docs below for more info about how in python 3 the print statement was replaced fully with the function: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html